# При обучении нейросети получаются огромные числа, который python воспринимает как null, inf и не может продолжать вычисления

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

обучаю нейросеть определять цифры на изображениях 24*24 px.

Принципиальное условие: не использовать библиотеки tensorflow, keras...

По мере того, как выполняется код, в промежуточных слоях нейросети получаются огромные числа, которые python воспринимает как nan и inf. После чего у него не получается выполнять дальнейшие действия.

**Вот пара мест, где происходит эта проблема:**

**1. Функция нормировки**(применяется только к последнему слою нейросети):

```
    def SoftMax(self, t2):
        out = np.exp(t2)
        return out/np.sum(out)
```

*Насколько я поимаю тут появляются **inf**, т.е. бесконечно большие числа.*

**2.** Для вычисления ошибки используется **категориальная кросс-энтропия**.

```
    def CrossEntropy(self):
        error = np.log(self.res_vector[np.argmax(self.y)])
        return error
```

*Насколько я понимаю тут порой появляются **nan**, т.е. бесконечно малые числа.*

**3.** Далее пытаюсь выполнить **градиентный шаг**, а там inf и nan уже лежат:

```
# Вручную вычисляем градиенты на каждом слое и корректируем веса. 
    def back_propogation(self):
        dE_dt = self.res_vector - self.y
        i = self.N-2

        while i >= 0:
            if i > 0:
                dE_dw = self.H[i][None, ...].T @ dE_dt[None, ...]
                dE_db = dE_dt

                alpha = 0.001
                self.M[i+1] += alpha * dE_dw
                self.B[i+1] += alpha * dE_db

                dE_dh = dE_dt @ self.M[i+1].T
                dE_dt = dE_dh * self.ReluDeriv(self.S[i])
                i -= 1
            if i == 0:
                dE_dw = self.S[0][None, ...].T @ dE_dt[None, ...]
                dE_db = dE_dt

                self.M[i+1] += alpha * dE_dw
                self.B[i+1] += alpha * dE_db

                break
```

*Ну и понятно, что в весах M[i] и B[i] уже не числа лежат...*

Надо сказать, Tensorflow я тоже изучил. И там всё тоже самое, также можно вызывать функции softmax и crossentropy, просто у них не происходит таких неприятных переполнений. Вот мне хочется узнать, что я должен исправить в этих функциях чтоб такой проблемы не возникало. И ещё вопрос, можно ли вообще эти функции как-либо менять, ведь тогда и градиент надо будет ссчитать по-другому...

Поясню, я вдохновялся следующим матреиалом: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOSf9rRg-fvJt5adxPbefB394QBtW9smZ

Автор видео сводит вычисления производных к перемножению матриц! Оно и логично, ведь зависимости везде линейные... Но его программа состояла из 1го промежуточного слоя, а моя - из произвольного количества нейронов. Именно поэтому в промежуточных слоях у меня накапливаются "плохие" числа :(

Я пробывал нормировать все значения на входном слое, пытался всячески зажимать интервалы в пределах от e^(-720) до e^(25), путем различных делений, и вроде всё было классно, но накапливаемая ошибка перестала уменьшаться в процессе обучения.

Мне показалось, что мои методы не работали, потому что python или numpy не ссчитал дробные числа дальше 7го знака после запятой... Во всяком случае в консоль так выводилось. Вообщем зашел в тупик, буду рад если окажете помощь :)

Приведу в пример несколько фото, может они внесут дополнительную ясность в то, что было по приложенной ссылке.

[image: План нахождения градиентов]

[image: Рис.1]

[image: Пример как автор советовал искать компоненты градиента]

[image: Пример как автор советовал искать компоненты градиента]

И вот эти формулы можно применять на каждом слое, поэтому они УНИКАЛЬНЫ. Вот я и обхожу в цикле все слои "справа-налево", и выполняю back-propogation. Заранее скажу, что backpropogation работает правильно, т.к. в тех случаях, когда по счастливой случайности переполнения НЕ возникали, нейросеть с точностью в 70% определяла цифры на тестовой выборке. А ещё очень приятно было смотреть на убывающую ошибку в процессе обучения...

Поэтому с уверенностью заверяю что **проблема в этих inf и nan**, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: В `Softmax` в `out` лежат нули и мы делим на 0. В `CrossEntropy` логарифм от 0. Может нейросеть, приходит к весам 0? Попробуйте уменьшить `alpha` иначе не знаю.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но проблема в том, что лежит там не 0, а число настолько близкое к нему, что в ячейку кладется nan. Это nan не воспринимается программой как число. Дальнейшие действия с этим числом ломают программу. А если бы вместо nan лежало число, то всё было бы хорошо.

Comment: У вас SoftMax возвращает отрицательные значения, а внутри логарифма отрицательные значения стоять не могут он возвращает nan. Не знаю как это исправить.

Comment: Извините, но "е" в любой степени - положительное число. Откуда там отрицательные числа возьмутся?

Comment: Скорее е^(-720) = 0.00000000000000001, = nan, то есть не является числом.

Comment: Извиняюсь в моей программе была ошибка.  Тогда просто добавьте 0.0001 перед тем как загонять в log вроде это где-то используют.

Comment: NaN - это не какая-то там малая величина, это не-число. Оно получается при попытке поделить 0/0, или взять логарифм от отрицательного числа. В общем, NaN говорит о нарушении ОДЗ функции.

Comment: Я вас услышал, но проблема с большими числами остается нерешенной. Я начинаю думать о том, что можно поменять функцию активации с Relu на Sigmoid…

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт nan и inf я понял:

[image: график логарифма]

На единице значение достигает нуля и и уходит в отрицательные, а там уже и nan недалеко.

[image: график экспоненты]

А здесь 50 похоже уже до бесконечности.
Но ваши текстовые утверждения верны.
Можно попробовать другую функцию нормировки, например сигмоиду.
И другой метод вычисления ошибки, например mean squared error.

Comment: Вы знаете, вы правы. Действительно, я то использую функцию активации Relu, но в этом есть назумная причина. При обратном распространении ошибки очень просто поссчитать градиент. Т.к. производная от Relu = 1, при х > 0 и 0, при x < 0.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось избавиться от нежелательных больших чисел в функции softmax, смотрите как:
https://russianblogs.com/article/87702691403/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но прикол в том, что когда мы отнимем M, мы рискуем получить супер-маленькое число и тогда в знаменателе, там где сумма, может появиться nan.

В целом, ошибка по-прежнему не пропала. Точности вычисления по-прежнему не хватает.

Comment: [лучше бы, конечно, словами, а не картинкой.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Вот ссылка на git, с моим проектком:
https://github.com/Koresh01/neiroset.git

Смотрите также ссылку(повторяю, вдохновлялся я этой идеей):
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOSf9rRg-fvJt5adxPbefB394QBtW9smZ
Суть в том, что автор учит нас искать градиенты, сводя вычисления производных к перемножению матриц.

Проблема в том, что я принципиально решил не пользоваться tensorflow, keras. И я искренне не понимаю, как бороться с очень большими/малыми числами, по типу inf, nan. Даже если зажать числа в диапазоне [a, b], где a,b - допустимы, точности знаков после запятой не достаточно.